# Delete Email section for users accounts - Cpanel

Tags: cpanel, whm

I want to disactivate the E-mail section for users profiles in the CPanel,
how can I do that?

I have tried to disable features from the Feature manager but I couldn't delete all the section

**UPDATE:**

I have solved the issue, just check the right features in the manager feature for the disable part

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible for web hosts, not for cpanel users.

In WHM you should go to the `feature manager` and you will find one or more profiles that can be applied to different hosting products.

Open the profile for the accounts you want to impact and you will see *all* the features that are available.  Uncheck the ones you don't want displayed.